# How to calculate "extra y ticks" value by function instead of giving a fixed value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    declare function={
        func(\x)= \x*\x;
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \xmin {-3}
\def \xmax {3}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin={\xmin}, xmax={\xmax},
    extra y ticks={9},
    extra y tick labels={$c$}]
\addplot [samples=100,domain={\xmin}:{\xmax}] {func(\x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I add `extra y ticks={9}`, but what I really want is to add `extra y ticks={func(\xmin)}`, thus the extra y tick label can be placed in the right place when the `\xmin` value changed. How can I write the code to calculate `extra y ticks` value by function instead of giving a fixed value? Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way is to compute it beforehand with, say after the `\def`s, `\pgfmathsetmacro\myextratick{func(\xmin)}` and then put that macro `extra y ticks={\myextratick}`

Comment: @percusse care for an answer?

Comment: @PaulGessler Oops I forgot.. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

CW from the comments:

Set the calculation into a PGF math macro and use the macro as the `extra y ticks` setting:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    declare function={
        func(\x)= \x*\x;
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \xmin {-3}
\def \xmax {3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\myextratick{func(\xmin)}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin={\xmin}, xmax={\xmax},
    extra y ticks={\myextratick},
    extra y tick labels={$c$}]
\addplot [samples=100,domain={\xmin}:{\xmax}] {func(\x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]